# Visual Studio 2013 can't connect to MySQL database using string but can using Data Source window

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013

After hours of searching I finally put a question on here.

Visual Studio is connect to my database perfectly using the Data Source window but can't find the server when using the string (Server=blah;Database=blah etc)

When connecting in my program it breaks with the message:
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll and The network path was not found

My affected code is listed below.

```
Private Sub OK_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles OK.Click
   Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=db4free.net;Database=[CENSORED];Uid=[CENSORED];Pwd=[CENSORED];")
   con.Open()
```

Yes the username, password, server, and database are correct as again, they work in the Data Sources window.

Comment: "network path was not found" seems to be the error.  can you create a system DSN and get that to work?

Answer (score 0):

Double check the conection string, it may be changed or mis spelled..
Because If it conects using the data source, then it should connect using connection string too..

Good luck

Comment: Nothing is misspelled but I am using the MySQL addon for Visual Studio to access the database in the Data Source window.